# Perdida de archivos al hacer un rebase en git

Tags: git

Les describo la situacion:
-hice un nuevo branch desde el proyecto principal.
-commit 1 (con push)
-commit 2 (con push)
-mergeo con cosas nuevas del principal
-commit 3 (con push)
-commit 4 (con push)
mergeo con cosas nuevas del principal

aca paso todos los test y me dijeron que haga un squash para meter un solo commit y no que aparezcan tantos.
Asi que hice git rebase -i head5
me muestra:
de la lista elimino todos los commit que no son mios y dejo el primero (el commit 1) como pick y el resto como fix.
Cuando empieza el rebase, es como que me trae unicamente los archivos del primer commit, todos los nuevos que cree en los otros commit no aparecen.

Estoy haciendo algo mal?, soy nuevo en esto pero leyendo varios lugares deberia funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

La técnica más sencilla es esta:

```
git checkout tu-rama-original # original antes del rebase
git merge la-rama-principal # con commit.... no hacer push
# aquí viene la magia
git reset --soft la-rama-original
# en este punto, en el index solo deben estar
# tus cambios, y más nada
# verificar con git status
# y con git diff --cached
git commit -m "un solo commit con todos mis cambios"
# ahora puedes hacer un git push -f hacia el remoto
```